# Initialize counter in LabVIEW

Tags: counter, labview

I inherited some LabVIEW that has a time counter on it. Although I don't completely understand it because I am not familiar to LabVIEW and I have been successful to some extent.

What I couldn't make though, is to initialize this counter.

[image]

And this is my unsuccessful attempt (it just doesn't progress anymore).

[image]

I've seen this question that seems similar, but it didn't help me to solve my problem.

Also, my attempt was based on this NI help: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvhowto/initializing_shift_registe/ after which I assumed it would work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what I believe you're going for. It now resets when first called or when the reset button is pressed. Also, I put a tiny wait in there to avoid unnecessary CPU loading.

The reason your attempt to fix it didn't work is because you were initializing the shift register of the timer every time it ran. That shift register has to be left uninitialized so it can retain the value from the previous run.

[image]

Comment: A zero wired to the wait will let other processes interrupt (same as the 1). Also, this could be simplified a bit: to get the elapsed time you only need to subtract the current time from the initial time, there's no need to increment by the time elapsed since the last iteration.

Comment: Why keep the inner loop? Move the shift registers to the outer loop and delete the inner loop entirely.

Comment: @srm I think the idea is that the inner loop will become a subvi and the outer one is there is there to facilitate running it. That's why I left it anyway.

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't add the extra clock between the two loops. What is that for?

Comment: @srm Yes, the outer loop is there because this is actually part of a bigger program.

Comment: @myradio That's the Wait primitive -- I think that's just there to give it something to time. It's a stand-in for whatever real code is happening in the outer loop while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of timer, with reset functionallity. It is done as FGV - [functional global variable](https://learn-cf.ni.com/teach/riodevguide/code/rt_functional-global-variable.html).
Below are screenshots of the each state:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]